# Allow users to input the location of an event IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am trying to construct an app for IOS 8 using swift in which users have the ability to post the location of an event, and people within a certain distance have the opportunity to see it based on their current location.

After looking around for awhile, I am getting the notion that this is not possible. I know it is possible if it is based on the user that posts current location (Yik Yak), but I am not if there is a way to let them actually input an address with maps.

Does anyone have a potential answer to this?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest that you try searching for CoreLocation in the web or here on SO. You really just need to Google this as there are many examples/tutorials with full code: Other keywords you could use include "current location","iOS", etc. So you might want to search first as there are many people who asked/answered this question on SO. As a result, this question just becomes repetitive. On SO, please search before posting or people will down vote. I chose to explain rather than down vote. Hope this is clear. Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly have a user insert locations and such by importing [MapKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html).